# Cache Google AppEngine documentation locally for offline use

Tags: java, google-app-engine, offline-caching, offline-browsing

The biggest problem when developing offline is the unavailability of documentation.

Google AppEngine used to provide a downloadable tar ball of its documentation, but doesn't seem to do so any more. So how do I get a local version of the AppEngine documentation, along with the ability to update it when required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem turned out to be to use `wget` to create a local mirror of GAE/J's documentation.

```
pushd ~/Docs
wget --mirror -nH -np --page-requisites --convert-links --cut-dirs=3 \
    -P GAEJ \
    https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/
```

Since the Q&A format of StackOverflow favours to-the-point answers, I wrote up a blog post with some more details (and for a more general use case): [Downloading or Caching (Technical) Documentation](http://hsjawanda.com/2014/03/09/downloading-or-caching-technical-documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/mj_VA3UCkD8

Actual command:

```
httrack -N100 -%k https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/
```